# Make a preg replace on string in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to find ou a way to make this in twig but I can't find a solution..

```
preg_replace('/(\w+)([A-Z])/U', '\\1 \\2', ucfirst("thisIsAnExample")) ;
```

The output in php is "This Is An Example"

Is it possible to do the same thing in twig ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to do a preg\_replace in twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573760/how-to-do-a-preg-replace-in-twig)

Comment: take a look at [this](https://github.com/jasny/twig-extensions) extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a [twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) which will create a custom function for you to use in twig.

For example:

```
/**
 * Convert camel case to a capitalised human readable string.
 *
 * @param $camelCase string
 * @return string
 */
public function camelCaseToString($camelCase)
{
    return preg_replace("/([A-Z])/", " $1", ucfirst($camelCase));
}
```

This should convert `thisIsAnExample` to `This Is An Example`.