# Isolate and wrap a numeral using a Twig filter?

Tags: twig

How can I use TWIG to isolate a numeral in a *string* and wrap it in a `<span>`? The string is always  rendered as such:
"Thu 4 Apr"

I tried this but the `<span>` is not being rendered:

`{{ date|replace({('(\\d+)'): '<span>$1</span>'})|raw }}`

Comment: Twig's `replace`-filter uses PHP's [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function which doesn't support Regex

Comment: Does this answer your question: [how to do a preg_replace in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573760/how-to-do-a-preg-replace-in-twig)